# Prevent Vim's autocmd from running on write just once

Tags: vim, autocmd

I have the following line in my `.vimrc` to automatically beautify js files after I save them:

```
autocmd BufWritePost *.js :call JsBeautify()
```

I want this 99% of the time, but sometimes I just want to write without having this function called. Is there an easy way to do that?

Answer (score 71, accepted):

I guess you're looking for `:noa`.

Usage:

```
:noa w
```

Excerpt from help:

> *:noautocmd* *:noa*
>
> To disable autocommands for just one command use the ":noautocmd" command
>   modifier.  This will set 'eventignore' to "all" for the duration of the
>   following command.  Example:
>
> ```
> :noautocmd w fname.gz
> ```
>
> This will write the file without triggering the autocommands defined by 
>   the
>   gzip plugin.